# Meaning of the phrase "pressed on" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

It is from this [article](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/europe/parallel-universe-the-front-runner-seeking-to-be-ukraines-president-plays-one-on-tv/2019/03/09/2a4cc22e-3a8c-11e9-b10b-f05a22e75865_story.html?noredirect=on&utm_term=.1f6e126780a5).

> **Pressed on** what he would do differently from Poroshenko in dealing with Putin, Zelensky said he would insist the Russian president explain his past actions and his demands on an official piece of paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there is a phrasal verb, "to press on" (meaning to continue moving forward), this is not that verb.

---

In this context,  Zelensky was pressed (i.e. asked repeatedly or in a forceful way) to say what he would do differently.

So we could have the following sentence, *"Pressed, Zelensky said he would insist ..."*

---

The structure of the original sentence looks as follows:

*Pressed, (on what he would do differently from Poroshenko in dealing with Putin), Zelensky said he would insist the Russian president explain his past actions and his demands on an official piece of paper.*

---

**Other possibilities**

*Quizzed on what he would do differently from Poroshenko ... Zelensky said he would insist ...*

*Interrogated on what he would do differently from Poroshenko ... Zelensky said he would insist ...*

*Asked about what he would do differently from Poroshenko ... Zelensky said he would insist ...*

Answer (score 0):

Verb usage 3.1, from the [Oxford English Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/press):

> Make strong efforts to persuade or force (someone) to do

Here is the sentence with this context substituted into it:

> When reporters made a strong effort to persuade Zelensky to say what he would do differently, he yielded to their demands and said he would insist…